# EEVEE or CYCLES - Render Lawn Grass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, scatter-objects-addon

Looking for quick tips on front yard lawn grass. There are many good tutorials show how to make grass, but wild landscape grass. how to make it look like it's not wild and uncut, yet real?

Answer (score 1):

I personally would recommend using Cycles and being heavy on your materials. Materials will really sell what your looking for. I recommend using this PBR node setup to help your grass look real
For Fresnel Node Group:
[image: Fresnel Node setup]

For PBR Node Group:
[image: PBR Node Setup]

However for modeling I would recommend just giving it a semi straight but wavy geometry.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, I'm looking forward to trying it.

Comment: No problem. hope it works out